# Для чего в дженериках используются <E> и <T>?

Tags: java, ооп, типы-данных, типы, преобразование-типов

Является ли это просто абстрактным обозначением, которое в реальном коде заменяется на другие типы (вроде String) или эти буквы тоже применяются в реальном коде, если да, то с какой целью?

```
public class SomeType<T> {
    public <E> void test(Collection<E> collection) {
        for (E element : collection) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
    public void test(List<Integer> collection) {
        for (Integer element : collection) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Да, это просто именование типов который впоследствии будут использованы внутри дженерика, а буквы разные, потому что типов может быть много.

Comment: Стало понятнее, но пока что не до конца, к примеру есть код (добавил в текст вопроса), для чего в нём используются <T> и <E>?

Comment: @НиколайСеменов это просто названия типов, которые еще не определены. В них нет отличия, хоть ты тип свой назови <MyType322> вместо <T>, ничего не изменится. Просто есть некоторые стандарты их именования. Так, например, буквой T помечают обычные типы, а буквой E - элементы коллекции.